# Material Design WPF Dialog Calendar UI bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, user-interface, material-design

When I was testing Material Design Dialogs and Pickers I found some UI bug for Calendar
[image]

This is my .xaml

```
                        <Button Margin="8 0 0 0"
                                Content="..."
                                Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}"
                                materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogOpenedAttached="CalendarDialogOpenedEventHandler"
                                materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogClosingAttached="CalendarDialogClosingEventHandler">
                            <Button.CommandParameter>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Calendar x:Name="Calendar"
                                              Margin="-1 -4 -1 0" />
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                                Margin="8"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="1"
                                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                                Content="OK" />
                                        <Button Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}"
                                                CommandParameter="0"
                                                Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                                Content="Cancel" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button.CommandParameter>
                        </Button>
```

Has someone had the similar bug with Calendar UI ?
How can I solve this ?

Comment: How can you solve what? What is the problem?

Comment: @BentTranberg UI for Calendar dialog. I marked by red squares. As you can see, lower Calendar dialog some doorstep displayed.

Comment: You should edit clarifying information into the question, and not add it through comments.

Comment: Well, with that margin set `<Calendar x:Name="Calendar" Margin="-1 -4 -1 0" />` I would expect such glitches :o)

Comment: @SirRufo why would you expect such glitches? Do you generally consider negativ margins a no-no and allow control developers to glitch on them or do you specifically expect material design controls to be authored without proper design stability?

Comment: @grek40 You have to know what you are doing with negative margins and when you get such a glitch as shown in the screenshot then you should check that negative margins at first. Simple Reaction to Action

Comment: @SirRufo Yep. My bad. Thanks a lot. In future try to examine my .xaml carefully.